# Equivalent of write in printf in the following code?

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I wanted to ask what will be the equivalent of this write statement in printf statement?

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf + start, end - start);
```

Where buf is a char*, start is int, end is int. 
The line which is confusing me is buf + start?
Or how can i save this to a char array using strcpy and then printf that char array. But i don't know how to copy the output of above code to char array. I am unable to understand what the line buf+start is doing.

thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to save the output of above line to a char array so that i can use it.

Comment: It's simple pointer arithmetic.  Are you looking for `memcpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy this data you need

```
char *mybuffer;
mybuffer = malloc(end - start + 1);
if (mybuffer != NULL)
{
    memcpy(mybuffer, buf + start, end - start);
    mybuffer[end - start] = '\0';
}
```

There you go, now `mybuffer` can be used in a `printf` like function, you need to remember to do `free(mybuffer)` at some point after you are done using `mybuffer`. Also you need to check `end - start >= 0` and be aware that if there is a `null` byte embeded into the data, the string will be shorter than `end - start` for what `printf` and family care.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) I was trying to do this with strcpy and was unable to do it. :)

Comment: If i want to return this mybuffer from a function, then where should i free it? As i cannot free it in the function where i have to return this mybuffer? @iharob

Comment: For e.g. i return this myBuffer from function A. And get it in another function B as char * line = A(); now if in function B after using char * line, i do free(line) will it actually free myBuffer?

Comment: Yes, `free` means release resources to the operating system, not clear memory or erase it.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `buf + start` uses pointer arithmetic and is equivalent to `&buf[start]`, the pointer to the position `start` in `buf`. The code you show prints the slice from `start` to `end` (exclusivley) of your char buffer `buf`.

If your buffer doesn't contain zeros, you can rewrite that as:

```
printf("%.*s", (int) (end - start), buf + start);
```

The cast to `(int)` isn't strictly necessary in your case, but the `*` precision in `printf` requires an `int` and one often uses `size_t` for positions, so I've made that a habit.

Comment: Good to have mentioned "If your buffer doesn't contain zeros".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what is with buffer not containing zeros?

Comment: Buffers containing zeros, you mean? The `printf` format `%s` is for printing strings, which are terminated with a null character, i.e. with a byte value of zero. If you set a precision `p` in the format, at most `p` characters will be printed, but printing will stop short when a null character is encountered. In short: `printf("%.6s", "Hi")` will print "Hi" and `printf("%.6s", "Good morning")` will only print "Good m".

Comment: You should mention that `str*` functions expect `null` terminated strings, and that the absence of a `'\0'` terminating byte is what really causes trouble.

Comment: @iharob: String formats with a precision doesn't necessarily expect a null-terminated string. In fact, it is designed to print strings that are delimited by their length. Still you would have to check that your buffer contains printable characters, though.